# double 404 requests for img, script. Every 404-resource requested twice in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-404

How can I remove unexpected requests to the backend?
Non-existing resources make the browser perform several requests to the backend, for example in this code:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sleep(ms) {
        ms += new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date() < ms){}
    }
    sleep(1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src='not_exist.jpg'>
    <script src='not_exist.js'></script>
</body>
```

each request for `not_exist.jpg` and `not_exist.js` is duplicated.

Sure, 404 is not good. But why does my browser request a resource two or more times following a 404 response? (Sleep or some other delay, may be more content to load and rendering really need. In fast case it may load one times)

I've tested this code on some versions of Chrome and Firefox, and always see 4 requests for only two resources. Every "404-resource" requests twice (this is not the case on mobile Safari).

[Here is a related bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648568), but you can try my simplest example and see how it works right now.

In the backend log I also see two requests for each 404-resource on every html-page request.
You can see it in JS console or in your backend logs too.

Comment: `You can see it in JS console or in your backend logs too` - no, my browsers behave correctly - have you tried running your browsers in safe mode (i.e. all addons/extensions disabled)

Comment: I take that back, Chrome does what you describe, Firefox 48 and 50 work correctly, internet explorer/edge untested

Comment: I see it both in console and in backend logs.

Comment: on Firefox 38 work correctly, but I tested on other desktop, I can check version later. My mobile chrome have this bug too.